# Accept and parse information from email

Tags: parsing, email, php

What I would like to accomplish is for a user to be able to send an email to a designated email address. Then once that email has been obtained, run a script that parses the body section of the email and carries out various tasks with the information provided in the email
(The data coming in from the email will be structured in an xml type format).

In my mind this seems like a simple task to accomplish but I'm not all that familiar with the inner workings of email. My questions are:

1. How will I know once an email has been obtained from the sender so that it can be processed?
2. How can I use php to obtain the text found in the email?

Comment: depending on your mail server you can pipe an incoming email to a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other responses, that piping to a php application should be your first option (if the mail server and php are the same)

Otherwise if you have an external mail server you will need to poll the email address at regular intervals and check for new emails.

Extracting plain text body from an email message is not too hard, but getting to attachments can be a pain sometimes.

You will need to use a cronjob to trigger your script at regular intervals

To fetch the email from the server and parse it, I have used the php IMAP functions
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

You can also use 3rd party services like MandrillApp which will receive the message, break it into parts, and call your application via a webhook.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP running on your mail server, then it's possible to pipe incoming mail to a PHP script.  Then, your PHP script can parse the body of each incoming message as it arrives.  See http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/ for more info.